# RadScheduler - Capturing Appointment Save from the EditAppointmentTemplate - Web

Tags: telerik, telerik-scheduler

I use **telerik radscheduler** on the web. I would like to do some **validation when a user clicks on the Save Button in the EditAppointmentTemplate window**. Is there any event that gets triggered that I will be able to use. I am seeing AppointmentSaving event in WPF, but not for the web.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the **OnAppointmentCommand** event as described in [Telerik's "Using Templates" Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/templates/defaultcs.aspx).